# what is the alternative of netapps?

Tags: storage

after long discussion with my client, they prefer to use netapps as solution for their storage consolidation even though from our perspective it won't answer the need to integrate their various storage server to be seen as one networked drive from their clien't pc

is there any other alternative to netapps?

Comment: Why won't it answer this need exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We chose to deploy 40TB managed by Nexenta include 2TB of SSD for 200k+ IOPS on a data intensive application.

Answer (score 3):

There's LOADS of alternatives - it depends on what they want to achieve and how. For instance a basic NetApp might only provide NFS services over a pair of 1Gbps ethernet links, a different system might provide iSCSI, NFS, SMB/CIFS, http, FC, FCoE etc. over a range of 10Gbps links. It may also include various data replication/sync services etc.

You need to decide what the customer wants, in these terms, then come back to us with their requirements and I'm sure you'll be deluged with alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about NAS oder SAN (Storage)? If NAS, CIFS or NFS?
Why should Netapp Filer not be able to export the storage as one network drive? I think that this is primary a job of the Protocol, not of the Storage System. On the Windows side DFS would solve that problem, and I am pretty sure that there is solution in the NFS world too.

Answer (score 1):

If the reason for using netapp is because of the flexibility of the WAFL filesystem, then i propose that opensolaris + zfs makes a competitive alternative.  So much so, that netapp are suing sun over their filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

we finally use Nexenta and gluster fs as those two combination result in robust solution in more affordable